# New to android development: What features will I lose out on if I choose to support Gingerbread with support libaries?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-support-library, android-2.3-gingerbread

I keep reading online that if possible, it makes sense to ditch the support libraries and develop only for 4.0+ devices. They all mention that this would would allow me access to "more features".

However, I cant seem to find any articles or questions that address these differences or specific features that I'll miss out on if I use the support libraries. I'm starting work on my first app and I'd love to get some inputs from the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support libraries add a specific subset of features, they do not aim to enable backwards compatibility for every feature added since 2.3.

So check out the list of compatibility features here: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

And compare it against the list of new platform features:
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html

To figure out what you're missing out on.

Edit: one quick example which comes to mind is the NumberPicker controller, which is in 3.0+ but NOT included in the support libraries (at time of writing)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into those links. If I use the support libraries, but wish the add the additional features for later versions, I can simply do the android version check in the code right? This should technically allow me to give pre-4.0 users at least a functional app. At the same time users with the new platform would have access to all the features. Or would this end up being too complex to implement?

Comment: I also read of another approach where developers release 2 versions of the app- one for pre-4.0 users and one for 4.0+ users. Would this be an easier/cleaner/faster approach?

Comment: I would strongly recommend having a single binary and doing your Android version check wherever new APIs come up in the runtime. Lint will warn you of any places where you're calling a newer API than your project target. Multiple binaries makes maintenance a headache!